# Maximizing average annual production

Tags: calculus

The total amount produced by a worker during the first $t$ years after being hired is:

$A=9+11t+.0064t^2$

Where $t>2$, what duration, $t$, maximizes the average annual production of the worker?

Answer (score 1):

The average is just $\frac At$.  Because the quadratic term in $A$ is positive, this can be made as large as you want by taking $t$ very large.  There is no maximum.